# In what order does postgresql handle queries which have conflicting locks?

Tags: postgresql, locking

Let's say that I have a long running query `SELECT` and this query holds a `AccessShareLock` on a table. While this query is being processed a new query which needs a `AccessExclusiveLock` on the table `REINDEXDB` is made. I suppose this query must wait the other query to finish, becuase they have conflicting locks. And while my `REINDEXDB` query is waiting for the `SELECT` query to finish, a second `SELECT` query is made. Now my question is

Which query will be serviced first? `REINDEXDB` or `SELECT`? Select query has been made later but it doesn't have a conflicting lock with the ongoing select query. So will they be processed in parallel? Or because `REINDEXDB` query has been made earlier will the second select query wait for `REINDEXDB` to finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't talk to postgresql directly. However, most rdbms in this situation would process the requests in the order they were received. That means a query can only execute if there is no other query that was submitted earlier and is either holding or waiting for a lock that is not compatible with the newly requested lock.

The reason is, that otherwise a query requesting an exclusive lock might never get executed ("starvation") if there is a high enough number/frequency of read requests coming in that keep sneaking by the waiting query.

Answer (score 2):

As testing can easily confirm, the second `SELECT` has to wait for the `REINDEX`.  Sebastian Meine's answer offers an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `AccessExclusiveLock` on the table when you know which index needs to be repaired. In this case you can use

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY
```

which doesn't lock the table. Let's say your index is called my_index, then you go like this:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY my_index_new ON ...;
DROP INDEX my_index;
ALTER INDEX my_index_new RENAME TO my_index;
```